# Экранирование '&' в ссылке

Tags: url

У меня есть урл, на который я делаю запрос:

```
https://example.com/c?url
```

где `url` это ссылка со своими параметрами.
Например -

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com?par1=123&par2=321
```

В итоге при передаче этой ссылки в качестве параметра на `example.com`, теряется весь текст после &. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Экранирйуте символ `&`, таким образом  `%26`. А вообще кончено, закодируйте строку в `url` формат, онлайн, на каком нибудь сервисе, по типу — https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode/